# How to fit my cover image to the container

Tags: html, css

i m trying to fit this image inside the container , when i use cover it grows out and only a small part shows and when i user contain it shrinks i tried other things but it is not working .

```css
.banner{
    
    background-image: url('banner1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgb(253, 235, 195);
 
}
```

Comment: can you attach minimal reproducible code snippet? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If text doesn't need to appear on top of the image maybe you should try just putting a img tag. You can stretch it with no sweat.

```
img{
        height:200px;//or whatever height you want for the banner
        width:100%;
    }
```